# Is it possible that the old primary follow the new secondary?

Tags: postgresql, repmgr

I need to change the roles between two nodes.

Circumstance:

2servers:

primary: psql01 and 
standby: psql02

After psql01 stops, psql02 becomes the new primary. After a while, start psql01

On psql01:

```
[-bash-4.2$ repmgr -f /var/lib/pgsql/repmgr/repmgr.conf cluster show
 ID | Name         | Role    | Status               | Upstream | Location | Priority | Timeline | Connection string
----+--------------+---------+----------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------------------------------------------
 1  | psql01       | primary | * running            |          | default  | 100      | 7        | host=psql01 user=repmgr dbname=repmgr
 2  | psql02       | standby | ! running as primary |          | default  | 100      | 8        | host=psql02 user=repmgr dbname=repmgr

WARNING: following issues were detected
  - node "postgresql02" (ID: 2) is registered as standby but running as primary](url)
```

On psql02:

```
repmgr -f /var/lib/pgsql/repmgr/repmgr.conf cluster show

     ID | Name         | Role    | Status    | Upstream | Location | Priority | Timeline | Connection string
    ----+--------------+---------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------------------------------------------
     1  | psql01       | primary | ! running |          | default  | 100      | 7        | host=psql01 user=repmgr dbname=repmgr
     2  | psql02       | primary | * running |          | default  | 100      | 8        | host=psql02 user=repmgr dbname=repmgr

    WARNING: following issues were detected
      - node "psql01" (ID: 1) is running but the repmgr node record is inactive
```

I try to put my old primary to standby with the following commands:

```
-bash-4.2$ repmgr -f /var/lib/pgsql/repmgr/repmgr.conf node service --action=stop --checkpoint
NOTICE: issuing CHECKPOINT
DETAIL: executing server command "sudo systemctl stop postgresql-11"
```

```
-bash-4.2$ repmgr -f /var/lib/pgsql/repmgr/repmgr.conf -d 'host=psql01 user=repmgr dbname=repmgr' node rejoin
ERROR: connection to database failed
DETAIL:
could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "psql01" (172.16.11.171) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

What's exaclty happen? If psql01 goes down how can I change the role to secondary?

Comment: did you read the documentation  from here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/warm-standby-failover.html

Comment: yes I read, but the error: "could not connect to server: Connection refused" appears becasue database is stopped. If database are down is it possible to run the command "repmgr node rejoin" ?

Comment: to my understanding no the databases have to be up and running to change there roles.  there may be away around this,  but i do not know it,  given no other comments have been posted,  My suggestion is post to postgresql general email list to try and get help there

Comment: If a node that was previously primary at startup is still, can I repmgr change its state? Maybe do aun update on repmgr database?

Answer (score 1):

On postgresql12:

```
systemctl stop postgresql-12.service

/usr/pgsql-12/bin/repmgr -f /etc/repmgr/12/repmgr.conf node rejoin --force-rewind --verbose -d 'host= psql02 user=repmgr dbname=repmgr connect_timeout=2' --dry-run
```

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. Could you possibly [edit] your answer and explain what would happen if your solution is applied? Are there any risks? Could something break? Would **you** try something that isn't explained? Consider having a peek at [answer] for some ideas. Help us increase the quality of DBA.SE together. Thanks.

Comment: Please also consider reading the [Markdown help](https://dba.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for hints on how to format questions and answers.